# Does google API allow us to get 'Usage of 3rd party apps authenticated through Google'?

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-gsuite

Does google API allow us to get 'List of user 3rd party apps authenticated through Google' ?
I can't find any references in documentation. But, it seems like it should be in API
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6294828?hl=en#zippy=%2Cautoprovisioning-status

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is to get the list of all the third party apps that your users have logged into using their Google accounts using the Google APIs. If so, what you can use is the [tokens.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/tokens/list) method, that way your will retrieve all the tokens a user has issued to 3rd party applications.

You can use the displayText and clientId values you get in the response to identify the app, and check the scopes to see the permissions of the app.